# How do I make k3b burn an audio CD with MP3 files?

Tags: mp3, burning, k3b

How do I make k3b burn an audio CD with MP3 files? Right now it's demanding I only feed it WAVs, of all things.

Comment: Audio CDs are .WAV files; your answer shows that you needed to install a codec to convert your .MP2s to .WAV

Comment: @LarsNordin 1. audio CDs don't contain wav files. the audio is written as one long stream, like a record. there is some (optional) metadata that defines the time a new track (eg song) starts. 2. wav is just an audio container format that usually contains uncompressed audio encoded as linear PCM. 3. audio CDs use linear PCM encoding without compression, so wav files are easy to work with. 4. the audio CD format is defined by the redbook specification

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`apt-cache search --names-only k3b` shows a codec package I don't have. I installed it via apt-get to solve:

```
sudo apt-get install libk3b6-extracodecs
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks that new k3b requires two packages to be installed; extra codecs and normalize-audio.

```
sudo apt-get install libk3b7-extracodecs normalize-audio
```